# Woocommerce localization problems

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am localizing woocommerce and facing this problem. On "shop" page, I have "showing" message which is printed this way:

```
printf( _x( '<p>Showing</p> <span> %1$d–%2$d of %3$d results </span>', '%1$d = first, %2$d = last, %3$d = total', 'woocommerce' ), $first, $last, $total );
```

So, I went to admin panel, located this message and entered the translation, generated new mo file, but nothing is changed on the page. This is also applies to other messages on this page. However, in header/footer/sidebar everything works ok.

From i18n/languages/woocommerce-lt_LT.po:

```
#: templates/loop/result-count.php:32
#, php-format
#@ woocommerce
msgctxt "%1$d = first, %2$d = last, %3$d = total"
msgid "Showing %1$d–%2$d of %3$d results"
msgstr "Rodomi rezultatai %1$d–%2$d iš %3$d"
```

Why messages are not displaying translated? What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In functions.php of theme there was:

```
$lang = get_template_directory_uri() . '/languages';
load_theme_textdomain($textdomain, $lang);
```

while should be:

```
$lang = get_template_directory() . '/languages';
load_theme_textdomain($textdomain, $lang);
```

so language simply has not been loaded